# Render JSON from GSP

Tags: json, grails, gsp

I have a few GSP pages that are returning JSON data. It looks like (only a lot larger)

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json" %>
{
  "foo": "${somevalue}"
}
```

And I am using this with the page renderer:

```
groovyPageRenderer.render view: '/renderService/foo', model: [foo: foo]
```

This works fine except that the values containing double quotes and other special characters are encoded with `&quot;` instead of `\"`

How can I force the encoding of these parameters to be JSON instead of HTML/XML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default codec for a particular GSP page with a directive:

```
<%@page expressionCodec="javascript" %>
```

More details in the [section on XSS prevention](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#xssPrevention) in the Grails user guide.

Comment: I also had a few conditional commas to separate list items that got encoded. I changed `${cond ? ','}` to `${raw(cond ? ',')} and it now works great. Thanks.